# Getting data from Mysql for highstock area graph.

Tags: mysql, highcharts

I am trying to get the highstock area chart getting data from Mysql. The sample provided on the highcharts website is calling the data from a csv file . How do i call that data from mysql server? for this particuar sample link :[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/areaspline/)

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                selected : 1
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data : data,
                type : 'areaspline',
                threshold : null,
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                fillColor : {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 0, 
                        y1: 0, 
                        x2: 0, 
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops : [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], 
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can get the data from **mysql** table in the form of **JSON** data using **PHP** and then use it in the above code, if share your table structure i can help you with code.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ~I am using mysql as my database where The name of my database is 'my database_dl' and table name is fuel_level and the fields that m using is 'date'(yy-mm-dd) and 'hours'(num:ex: 23).

Comment: so on x-axis you want date(yy-mm-dd) and on y-axis you want hours(only hours)?

Comment: Yes thats correct ! and those value for hours has to come from mysql database table. the file that i included above is using the data from a csv file . if u dont mind please give me your email or u can reply me back on divyesh@ems.gen.nz. thanks a lot

Comment: this is my email id : ashok.paritala@gmail.com,  send you table's schema to my mail i will try to send you the code.

Comment: I have emailed you ! thanks a lot

Comment: That is solved. I would also wanted one more help on this. I have made graph in php which uses mysql data. Now i am making a column graph which uses values from the database to display the graph. Now wht i want is for exmaple: value is 70 in the database so it will show the bar till 70 BUT wht i want is to show the remaining 30 . total is 100%. I will email you my codes and some description. and sample graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you,
Use the below code to get data from database

change the table name and column names as per your database and table

**data.php**

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("host","username",'password')or die("server not connected");
    mysql_select_db("database name")or die("db is not selected");
    header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');

    $sql="SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(date,'+00:00', @@session.time_zone))*1000,hours FROM engineHours order by date";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);

    $rows=array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        $rows[]="[".implode(',',$row)."]";

    }
    echo "[".implode(',', $rows)."]";
?>
```

And user data.php in the JQuery code

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {
```